# Host Katana in UWP app

Tags: asp.net-core, uwp, owin, katana, windowsiot

With all the changes moving to ASP.NET Core, I am not quite sure where Katana fell in the process, so apologies if this has been answered previously.

Previously, we could host Katana in a Console Application or Class Library. However, since Katana has been integrated into ASP.NET, it seems increasingly unlikely we will see UWP support for `Microsoft.Owin`.

Given that, is there another method of using OWIN for hosting web services (i.e. Web API or Nancy) in a UWP application?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> With all the changes moving to ASP.NET Core

Ref [Introduction to ASP.NET Core](https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/intro.html)

ASP.NET Core is a new open-source and cross-platform framework for building modern cloud based internet connected applications, such as web apps, IoT apps and mobile backends

You can develop and run your ASP.NET Core apps **cross-platform** on **Windows, Mac and Linux**.

> is there another method of using OWIN for hosting web services

This is an unreasonable requirement, UWP app is not appropriate to host server-side Web service. If you see the [App lifecycle](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/launch-resume/app-lifecycle), you will find the App execution state may block the service logic operation if the app hosts a service.

If we need to provide services to other UWP apps, creating and consuming an app service is the right direction: [Create and consume an app service](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/launch-resume/how-to-create-and-consume-an-app-service)

Comment: I was actually authoring a UWP app for Windows IoT, where having both an interface and a remote control method would be advantageous. I suppose I will have to look into using an app service

Comment: @agc93 This repository may be helpful: https://github.com/ms-iot/samples